# Calculate inactive customers from single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with fields Customer.No. , Posting date, Order_ID . I want to find total inactive customers for last 12 months on month basis  which means they have placed order before 12 months back and became in active. So want calculate this every month basis to under stand how inactive customers are growing month by month.
if I run the query in July it should go back 365 days from the previous month end and give total number of inactive customers. I want to do this month by month.
I am in learning stage please help.
Thanks for your time in advance.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Sample data & expected results would be nice too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query. To achieve your goal you need calendar table (which I defined with CTE). Below query counts inactivity for the first day of a month:

```
declare @tbl table (custNumber int, postDate date, orderId int);
insert into @tbl values
(1, '2017-01-01', 123),
(2, '2017-02-01', 124),
(3, '2017-02-01', 125),
(1, '2018-02-02', 126),
(2, '2018-05-01', 127),
(3, '2018-06-01', 128)

;with cte as (
    select cast('2018-01-01' as date) dt
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, dt) from cte
    where dt < '2018-12-01'
)

select dt, sum(case when t2.custNumber is null then 1 else 0 end)
from cte c
left join @tbl t1 on dateadd(year, -1, c.dt) >= t1.postDate
left join @tbl t2 on t2.postDate > dateadd(year, -1, c.dt) and t2.postDate <= c.dt and t1.custNumber = t2.custNumber
group by dt
```

Comment: @Cato I am using with CTE but the numbers are high ,how to no t count new customers ?

Comment: @jiroe What do you mean? Can you show example data of new customer? It works with data you showed.

Comment: Hi Michal, as Cato said I have used his last code ,the numbers are higher than expected. As he mentioned Am I need to filter new customers ?

Comment: @ Michal Turczyn At joins you have mentioned @tbl is that my table from database ?

Comment: @jiroe In place of `@tbl` you have to put your table name.

Comment: Turkzyn I can not insert values as there are many rows as per your example in the table. Could you please help without inserting values.

Comment: @jiroe Just don't copy `insert` statement. Start copying with `;with cte...` line. In the `select` statement change column names to your column names and `@tbl` to your table name.

Comment: Turczyn Sure, running this,it is been 26 mins now still executing.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

to get the customers

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.CustomerNo 
             FROM YourTable a 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                     (SELECT 0 FROM YourTable b WHere a.CustomerNo = b.CustomerNo 
                                                      and b.PostingDate > 
                                                 dateadd(day,-365 -datepart(day,getdate()),getdate())
                     )
```

to get a count

```
 SELECT DISTINCT count(0) as InnactiveCount 
             FROM YourTable a 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                     (SELECT 0 FROM YourTable b WHere a.CustomerNo = b.CustomerNo 
                                                      and b.PostingDate > 
                                                 dateadd(day,-365 -datepart(day,getdate()),getdate())
```

..
generate a 'months' table by CTE, then look for inactive in those months

```
;WITH month_gen as (SELECT dateadd(day,-0 -datepart(day,getdate()),getdate()) eom, 1 as x
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT dateadd(day,-datepart(day,eom),eom) eom, x + 1 x FROM month_gen where x < 12 
                    )
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(7), month_gen.eom, 102), count(0) innactiveCount FROM YourTable a 
                                                                        cross join month_gen 
                                                                        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM YourTable b WHere a.CustomerNo = b.CustomerNo and 
                                                                                               YEAR(b.PostingDate) = YEAR(eom) and 
                                                                                               MONTH(b.PostingDate) = MONTH(eom) 
                                                              ) 
                                                              GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(7), month_gen.eom, 102)
```

if that gets you anywhere, maybe a final step is to filter out anything getting 'counted' before it was ever active i.e. don't count 'new' customers before they became active

Comment: Hi Cato, I want to get count month wise not in total. Thank you

Comment: If you run that every month you'll get all the inactive customers and you can just compare the numbers.

Comment: Just added Results expecting.

Comment: Hi Aaron, do you mean with where clause with date field.